# Unexpected Behavior in Laravel Date Serialization

Tags: php, laravel, date

I've encountered a peculiar issue with date serialization in Laravel, and despite diving into the documentation, I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. Consider the following scenario:

I have a model with a `created_at` timestamp, and I'm using Laravel's default serialization in my API responses. However, when I retrieve the serialized data, the date format is not what I expect.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```php
// Model
class MyModel extends Model {
  // ...
}

// Controller
public function show($id) {
  $data = MyModel::find($id);
  
  return response()->json($data);
}
```

The resulting JSON includes the `created_at` field, but the date format is not what I've configured in my `config/app.php` or using the `dateFormat` property in the model.

I've tried using the `Carbon::serializeDate` method in my model, but the issue persists.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, how did you resolve it? Am I missing something in the serialization process or overlooking a configuration that affects date formatting in Laravel's default serialization?

Thanks for any insights!

I expected the serialized `created_at` field to adhere to the specified format, such as `y:m:d h:i:s` format.

Comment: Give examples of what output you're expecting and what you're actually getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019714/how-to-handle-json-responses-for-models-that-include-carbon-dates-on-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Customize Serialization by defining an accessor method

```
//In your Model
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->asDateTime($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

//In your controller

public function show($id) {
    $data = MyModel::find($id);
  
    return response()->json($data);
}
```